# Is there a numpy built-in to do this?

Tags: python, numpy

while doing BoxBlur exercise from CodeSignal, it asks to split the image matrix into a 3x3 sub-matrix, like this:

```py
[[7,4,0,1],          [[7, 4, 0], [5, 6, 2], [6, 10, 7]] 
 [5,6,2,2],   --->   [[4, 0, 1], [6, 2, 2], [10, 7, 8]] 
 [6,10,7,8],         [[5, 6, 2], [6, 10, 7], [1, 4, 2]] 
 [1,4,2,0]]          [[6, 2, 2], [10, 7, 8], [4, 2, 0]]
```

I wrote this following code, where it solves the problem with pure python:

```py
def get_grid(matrix, height, width):
    for i in range(len(matrix) - height + 1):
        for j in range(len(matrix) - width + 1):
            yield [row[j:j+width] for row in matrix[i:i+height]
```

Also I tried something with **numpy** that produces the same result:

```py
# in this case the matrix come as a numpy.array
def get_grid(matrix, height, width):
    for i in range(len(matrix) - height + 1):
        for j in range(len(matrix) - width + 1):
            yield matrix[i:i+height, j:j+width]
```

I wonder if there is somehow to produce the same results with numpy built-in or a more pythonic way.

Comment: `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, (3,3))`, IIUC

Comment: @Michael maybe with `.reshape(-1,3,3)`?

Comment: @mozway - Yes, but OP's own solution might be even better for some use cases

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny this worked nice! About the exercise it also asks for mean of each 3x3 grid, I could handle it by `[[grids[i, j].mean(dtype=int) for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]`. Idk if it's possible to do it with numpy, but I could simplify my code a lot! Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this from the suggestions of the comments to get this off the unanswered queue. You can use `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` to get the "convolution" sliding window values with specified size. In your example

```
import numpy as np

A = [[7,4,0,1],
     [5,6,2,2],
     [6,10,7,8],
     [1,4,2,0]]

res = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(A, (3,3)).reshape(-1, 3, 3)
```

You will need to reshape since the resulting shape would be `(2, 2, 3, 3)` otherwise.